# Android The list needs to slide horizontally, the items in the middle of the screen are enlarged, and the spacing between each item remains the same

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, interaction

Now there is a UI requirement: the list needs to slide horizontally, the items in the middle of the screen are enlarged, and the spacing between each item remains the same
The specific requirements are shown in the figure

[image]

How can I implement it

Comment: java or kotlin? xml layouts or compose? The type of component you're asking about is known as a carousel. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/motionlayout/carousel might be helpful